# Simple Perl CGI Script from HTML

Tags: html, perl, cgi

Hi folks I'm trying to do a simple CGI with 2 submit buttons, which do something on a database if you press them. Still I know I'm missing something because i can't seem to get it working.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form action="submit.pl" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="Inicio" value="Inicio" id="Inicio" Inicio />
<input type="submit" name="Finaliza" value="Finaliza" id="Finaliza" Finaliza />
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

submit.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=sms;host=10.0.0.1";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,"user","password123");


if ($q->param('Inicio')) 
    my $query = "insert into comienzo_programa (fecha, hora_inicio) values (CURDATE(),     CURTIME())";
$dbh->do($query);
} elsif ($q->param('Finaliza')) {
     my $query = "insert into comienzo_programa (hora_fin) values (CURTIME()) where   fecha=CURDATE()"; 
$dbh->do($query);
}
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: where fecha='CURDATE()', remove the single quote.

Comment: You have a `</form>` before your submit buttons.

Comment: Now It's starting to get into shape. It now displays the script once I click the button. Thank you.

Comment: Moved, submit.pl to cgi-bin folder. and configuring Apache.

Comment: One `}` is missing at line 12, after `Inicio')) `.

Comment: I would give your two submit buttons the same name, and then check the value of that name.

Answer (score 1):

Your <form> is in the <head>, instead of the <body>, which looks peculiar.

Comment: Fixed, on post and on site. Still, no luck.